# Isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

I came across this statement and I can't find an argument to prove it:

Every cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a quotient subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/(p − 1)\mathbb{Z}$, where $p_i$ is a prime number such that $p \equiv 1 \mod n$.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it just some very complicated formulation of *$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/(nk)\mathbb{Z}$?*

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $n\mid m$, then $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, $x+m\mathbb Z\mapsto x+n\mathbb Z$ is an epimorphism.